# Export Project into standalone .swf File

Tags: flash, export, flvplayback, flashbuilder4

I am trying for quite some while now to find an answer on how to export a FlexProject into a standalone SWF file.
I have a FLV video which I put into the flvplayback Container and added the skin from Flash CS4.
So all it is ist just a simple Videoplayer. 
We are working on a E-Learning Project and I want to put those Videos into the Main Application which was built with Flex 3.5, so to make things easier I need that standalone SWF Version of those Videos so my Teammates can just load them into the application with the flex swfloader.

I really hope I made myself clear, sorry English isnt my native language.

Here is the code from my project:

```
    public function init() {

    videoHolder1.addChild(debug);

    }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
<video:FLVPlayback id="debug"
                   source="../Videos/Debug.flv"
                   scaleMode="maintainAspectRatio"
                   skin="../Skins/SkinUnderAllNoCaption.swf"
                   skinAutoHide="false"
                   width="960"
                   height="540"
                   skinBackgroundColor="#011293"

                   autoPlay="false"
                   />
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:UIComponent id="videoHolder1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for images you shoul do this. then image will be in swf. for videos i guess it similer. you need to try.

```
[Embed(source="images/logo.gif")]
[Bindable]
public var imgCls:Class;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I didnt really get how to apply those lines of code to my problem. Can you show me the embed function with my code ? Thank you very much.